# export separate art boards as PNG illustrator script

Tags: javascript, scripting, jsx, adobe-illustrator

I've created to a simple illustrator script to loop through the artboards and export each as a PNG back into the folder that the original illustrator file is in. At least I thought I had. I don't need to do anything complicated with layers or different formats this is just a speed up production sort of a thing. I'm a bit rusty on .jsx and appreciate there are similar solutions out there, but I can't get this to run. It seems to fail on the doc.ExportFile line but I really can't see what I'm doing wrong. I'd appreciate anyone taking a look:

```
var doc = activeDocument;;//Gets the active document
var numArtboards = doc.artboards.length;//returns the number of artboards in the document
var basePath  = new File($.fileName).parent.fsName;

$.writeln(doc)
var options;
options = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
options.artBoardClipping = true;  
      options.matte = false;  
      options.horizontalScale = 100;
      options.verticalScale = 100;  
      options.transparency = true;  

for (var i = 0; i < numArtboards; i++ ) {
    doc.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex( i );
var artboardName = doc.artboards[i].name;        
            var destFile = new File('/' + artboardName + ".png");

    doc.exportFile(destFile, ExportFormat.PNG24 , options);
}
```

Comment: I now have this running without any errors but get no PNG output.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem seemed to be that you hve to have a destination path with the file name. This now seems to work: (You may need to altter the fileNamr generation as code just gets the first nune letters of a filename)

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;;//Gets the active document
var fleName = doc.name.slice(0, 9)//Get the file code number not the full name;
var numArtboards = doc.artboards.length;//returns the number of artboards in the document
var filePath = (app.activeDocument.fullName.parent.fsName).toString().replace(/\\/g, '/');

$.writeln("fleName= ",fleName)
$.writeln("numArtboards= ",numArtboards)
$.writeln("filePath= ",filePath);

var options = new ExportOptionsPNG24();

for (var i = 0; i < numArtboards; i++ ) {
    doc.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex( i ); 

    options.artBoardClipping = true;  
    options.matte = false;  
    options.horizontalScale = 100;
    options.verticalScale = 100;  
    options.transparency = true;  

    var artboardName = doc.artboards[i].name;
    $.writeln("artboardName= ", artboardName);
        var destFile = new File(filePath + "/" + fleName + " " +  artboardName + ".png");
        $.writeln("destFile= ",destFile);
          doc.exportFile(destFile,ExportType.PNG24,options);
    }
```