# Javascript to relink missing link from pdf within same folder within Illustrator

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to figure out a script to relink a linked pdf in Illustrator. Basically my file will have two linked pages from a pdf in illustrator. The file will then export images made from artboards from specific sections in each page. I will be repeating this 250 times so, it would be awesome if I could automate it.

Each images.ai file will be in separate folders, along with the pdf I would like to replace the linked pdf with. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: If the linked pdfs have the same names Illustrator relinks them (updates with another pdfs with the same names) automatically from current folder in case there is no access to the original folder and the original pdfs. So all you need is to rename (or move) the original folder of pdfs. If your pdfs have different names how the script can get the new names? Do you mean to input the new names manually 250 times, every time the script asks you?

Comment: Hi Yuri! The pdfs will have different names each time, but they will have the same name as the parent folder. I was hoping to either use a wildcard like '*.pdf' to find a pdf in the same folder as the activeDocument or use a variable to find the parent folder name + '.pdf'.

Comment: If there are two pdfs they can't have the same (as their folder) name. So it would be nice if you provide more information about your workflow. The task looks quite doable, but it's need to describe more closely before try to write a code.

Comment: Sorry, I should've explained that better. It is one pdf document, but it has two pages.

Comment: It's a very important information. Since Illustrator quite bad handles multi-page pdfs. I wouldn't surprised if it's not possible at all with a script to place or update a non-first page of a pdf. https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/place-pdf-pages-in-illustrator/td-p/4170988 Perhaps there is some extremely cumbersome workaround but I not sure. I see two more or less normal options: 1) Split the linked pdfs into two single-paged pdfs or 2) use InDesign instead of Illustrator, it's able to link/update multi-page pdfs via script.

Comment: Just in case, here is the script AI_MultiPagePDFLoader.jsx: https://gist.github.com/Dreyer/895c90ce6351de2652819ad0122ccea3 that allegedly imports (not links, but opens, copies and pastes) multipage pdfs into a new AI file as artboards. But it doesn't work for me by some reason. I can't recommend you this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevertheless, even though Illustrator doesn't handle multi-page pdfs via script this simply solution works somehow fine on my test files:

```
d:\test
│
├───folder1
│       ├───artwork.ai
│       └───folder1.pdf
│
├───folder2
│       ├───artwork.ai
│       └───folder2.pdf
│
└───folder3
        ├───artwork.ai
        └───folder3.pdf
```

It iterates through the folders `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`, opens the files `artwork.ai` and updates the links with `folder1.pdf`, `folder2.pdf` and `folder3.pdf` respectively.

```
var main_folder = Folder('d:/test');
var dirs = main_folder.getFiles();

for (var i=0; i<dirs.length; i++) {
    var dir = dirs[i];
    if (dir instanceof Folder) update_links(dir);
}

function update_links(dir) {
    var ai_file = File(dir.fullName + '/artwork.ai');
    var doc = app.open(ai_file);
    var pdfs = doc.placedItems;
    var new_pdf = File(dir.fullName + '/' + dir.name + '.pdf');
    for (var i=0; i<pdfs.length; i++) pdfs[i].relink(new_pdf);
    // doc.save();
    // doc.close();
}
```

Surprisingly it keeps intact original pages of the linked pdfs. Try it.

Comment: That worked great! You truly are the man. Thank you so much!

Comment: my next task is to export the artboards for screens from each file. Any ideas on how to do that? Or can you point me in the direction of a starting place to find the answer?

Comment: I think I have it most of the way figured out with this, but it looks like crap because it is exporting the images at 72ppi, not 300. There's gotta be a way to just run a export for screens. But, I can't seem to figure it out.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57144369/export-separate-art-boards-as-png-illustrator-script

Comment: Ok, I have it figured out now. Had to use imageCapture. It turns out perfect. Anyway, thank you again for the help Yuri! Hope everything is well with you!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57178400/set-resolution-when-exporting-artboards-to-png-using-script

Comment: imageCapture — a great trick. I didn't know it. Thank you too.